# how can I fetch css of a website using php

Tags: php, html, css, colors

I wanted to find colors from a website using php,

I can fetch the source code of a website but not able to fetch css files of a website,

is it possible to fetch external css of website,

Thanks,

Comment: uh, you can can fetch any file that you can come up with a valid url for. so, yes... it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the Website, search with a Regex for the CSS, fetch the CSS, search with a Regex for the Color Codes in the CSS. You must get the filename of the CSS from the HTML-Page to fetch it. There ist no way to do this automatically, except a manual search.

Comment: I did the same way, finally I used the css parser for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use HTTrack Website Copier, it will download all the files of the website, including the css file.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim to find the colors from website use addon called "**colourzilla**" available in FireFox.It ll be more than handy and i also dont think that it is possible to fetch the css file of a website. 
p.s.: not sure though.

Comment: yea.. use "firebug" addon in firefox to view the css content of the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Firebug Web developer Add-ons for firefox. Using that you can able to search HTML, CSS and JS code. And for color picking you can use Colorzilla Add-on.

Here is the link for firebug:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/